# What happens when you overfill your oil?

Tags: ford, oil, oil-leak, gasket

So I done recognized my oil was low... cuz on the dipstick, the two lil dots that are cut out of it... well... the oil was clear below both of em... even the LOW one.  SO I went and got some STP and slapped it in there... I put in 1.5 jugs of it.  They are quart size.

But now I'm nervous cuz I'm gettin some extra symptoms like a nasty stank when I rev it up real good goin up a hill... some people say it could be a valve cover gasket leak sprayin oil onto the manifold and burnin up and evaporatin and blowin in through the vents.

So I guess my questions is, what are the results of done slappin too much oil in your vehicle, BUT more precisionwise, is a valve cover gasket leak happen by such a practice?

Thanks very much.
-Bubba.

PS - my dipstick has got caddywumpus and I am suspectin that could cause messed up readings... makin it seem empty when it is actually full.  The dipstick is all twisted up and weird... somebody really done a number on it... Ford 98 5.4 v8 e150.

Comment: One thing you could do is to do a **full** service on your vehicle, all the filters, oils, check the brakes at each corner and get everything to a baseline so you know what is what. Otherwise it seems like every time you open the hood you ask a question.

Comment: How much overfill would have to be known to answer this.